# redirect from www on IIS

Tags: iis, web-server

How do you set up IIS so that when someone types in www.yourdomain.com it changes to yourdomain.com without the www.?

one example of this is www.twitter.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options.  If it's IIS7, definitely consider URL Rewrite.  For IIS 6 I would consider ISAPI Rewrite ([www.isapirewrite.com](http://www.isapirewrite.com)).

If you use your own server, setup a redirect site with www.yourdomain.com for the bindings and add a full redirect to yourdomain.com.  Basically have 2 full sites.

As you could handle it from code too, although the previous options are usually better.